# PHP 5.4 - Traits and self / static

Tags: php, static, constructor, traits

I want to chain method calls on my classes as follows :

```
new Obj($args, $if, $any)->foo()->bar();
```

Unfortunatly i have to enclose the construction within parenthesis :

```
(new Obj($args, $if, $any))->foo()->bar();
```

So i would like to have a trait that i could reuse in every class i want to be able to do something like :

```
Obj::create($args, $if, $any)->foo()->bar();
```

I want it to be a trait so my classes can still inherit from other classes.
I've come to that point :

```
trait Create
{
    public static final function create()
    {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(/* self ? static ? Anything else ? */);
        return $reflect->newInstanceArgs(func_get_args());
    }
}

class Obj
{
    use Create;

    // ...
}
```

But it seems like traits don't handle self or static keywords, and i can't do `get_class($this)` since this is static.
Is there a clear way to do what i want please ?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT : For those who wonder, here is why i want it to be a trait and not an abstract base class :

```
$database = (new Database())
    ->addTable((new Table())
        ->addColumn((new Column('id', 'int'))
            ->setAttribute('primary', true)
            ->setAttribute('unsigned', true)
            ->setAttribute('auto_increment', true))
        ->addColumn(new Column('login', 'varchar'))
        ->addColumn(new Column('password', 'varchar')));

$database = Database::create()
    ->addTable(Table::create()
        ->addColumn(Column::create('id', 'int')
            ->setAttribute('primary', true)
            ->setAttribute('unsigned', true)
            ->setAttribute('auto_increment', true))
        ->addColumn(Column::create('login', 'varchar'))
        ->addColumn(Column::create('password', 'varchar')));
```

Less bracket depth, less mistakes, and less time needed to fix these mistakes, plus an easier to read code, and, in my opinion, a better looking code.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with using brackets??

Comment: Reducing the number of brackets is reducing the probability of doing mistakes by forgetting one of them and the time needed to fix it as well as making the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: hmm, well, to be honest, I'd say that the code with the brackets is perfectly readable, especially if you're using a decent IDE. But each to their own.  :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is [**`get_called_class()`**](http://php.net/get_called_class), which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks ! :D The way their new features work is not that intuitive to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you don't want to use brackets -- it's not exactly the worst syntax in the world (in fact, I'd argue that from a visual perspective it's nicer than the double colon syntax you want to replace it with)

But if you do want to have a factory method like this on all your classes, why not just create a base class that all your other classes extend from that defines the `create` method? I don't see that you need a trait for it.

```
class BaseClass {
    public function create() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then all other classes `extends BaseClass`, where you don't have `extends` already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i explained, simple inheritance is the reason.

Comment: if this is a base class, and your core classes extend it, then the classes that extend them will also have it. If it's going to be a feature of all your classes, then a base class like this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yes, but in a situation where i can't make the classes inherit from this BaseClass so that sub classes inheritfrom it too, a trait comes in handy. Besides, reusing a method or a set of method is the exact purpose of a trait.

Answer (score -2):

**Traits** is a new feature in PHP. this feature introduce in version 5.4. This is substitute of multiple inheritance in PHP

**EXAMPLE:**

```
trait Net
{
    public function net()
    {
        return 'Net';
    }
}

trait Tuts
{
    public function tuts()
    {
        return 'Tuts';
    }
}

class NetTuts
{
    use Net, Tuts;
    public function plus()
    {
        return 'Plus';
    }
}

$o = new NetTuts;
echo $o->net(), $o->tuts(), $o->plus();
```

output is : NetTutsPlus

```
echo (new NetTuts)->net(), (new NetTuts)->tuts(), (new NetTuts)->plus();
```

output is : NetTutsPlus

with the help of object $o we can access **trait** function value..